# How to grab range of IPs in subnet with Ansible ipaddr

Tags: ansible

I have a subnet (i.e. 192.168.1.0/24) and I need to grab the first 33 IP addresses from this subnet in order to create 33 ports in OpenStack using the `os_port` module.

As it stands, I have the module configured as:

```
- name: reserve ports for {{ item.network }}
  os_port:
    state: present
    network: "{{ item.network }}"
    fixed_ips:
      - ip_address: "{{ item.ip }}"
  environment: "{{ openstack_environment_vars }}"
  loop: "{{ reserved_ips }}"
  run_once: true
```

And it goes through a list that looks like:

```
reserved_ips:
  - ip: 192.168.1.1
    network: test
  - ip: 192.168.1.2
    network: test
  - ip: 192.168.1.3
    network: test
  - ip: 192.168.1.4
```

This works just fine, however, in an effort to avoid having to create a long list of individual IPs I am looking for a way to simplify this.

I've looked into ipaddr to go through a subnet and add the IPs I need but from I can see I can only query one IP or one subnet at a time. How can I use Ipaddr to grab the first 33 IPs for me.

Ideally, the plan is to go through something like this:

```
- name: reserve ports for {{ item.network }}
  os_port:
    state: present
    network: "{{ item.network }}"
    fixed_ips:
      - ip_address: "{{ cidr | ipaddr ('1-33') }}"
  environment: "{{ openstack_environment_vars }}"
  loop: "{{ reserved_ips }}"
  run_once: true
```

```
reserved_ips:
  - cidr: 192.168.1.0/24
    network: test
  - cidr: 172.16.1.0/24
    network: test2
```

Any suggestions on how to filter through the first 33 IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use [with_sequence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/sequence.html#sequence-generate-a-list-based-on-a-number-sequence) and [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html#subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries)

The playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        sub1: "{{ sub1 | default([]) + [item | int] }}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end=3
    - set_fact:
        sub2: "{{ sub2 | default([]) + [item | int] }}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end=3

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    reserved_ips:
      - cidr: 192.168.1
        network: test
        sub: "{{ sub1 }}"
      - cidr: 172.16.1
        network: test2
        sub: "{{ sub2 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "ip:{{ item.0.cidr }}.{{ item.1 }} network:{{ item.0.network }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ reserved_ips }}"
        - sub
```

gives:

```
"msg": "ip:192.168.1.1 network:test"
"msg": "ip:192.168.1.2 network:test"
"msg": "ip:192.168.1.3 network:test"
"msg": "ip:172.16.1.1 network:test2"
"msg": "ip:172.16.1.2 network:test2"
"msg": "ip:172.16.1.3 network:test2"
```

The playbook can be simplified with [next_nth_usable](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/docs/docsite/rst/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.rst#finding-ip-addresses-within-a-range)

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    reserved_ips:
      - network: test
        cidr: 192.168.1.0/24
        ip_start: 1
        ip_end: 3
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: loop-task.yml
      loop: "{{ reserved_ips }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: iitem
```

with included file loop-task.yml

```
- debug:
    msg: "ip:{{ iitem.cidr|next_nth_usable(item|int) }} network:{{ iitem.network }}"
  with_sequence: "start={{ iitem.ip_start }} end={{ iitem.ip_end }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": "ip:192.168.1.1 network:test"
"msg": "ip:192.168.1.2 network:test"
"msg": "ip:192.168.1.3 network:test"
```

Answer (score 2):

Ansible's `ipaddr` filter plugin makes life needlessly complicated.  You can make your life easier by writing your own filter plugin.  Create a `filter_plugins` directory adjacent to your playbook, and put the following in `filter_plugins/ipaddr_extrra.py`:

```
import netaddr


def filter_to_network(value):
    return netaddr.IPNetwork(value)


class FilterModule(object):
    filter_map = {
        'to_network': filter_to_network,
    }

    def filters(self):
        return self.filter_map
```

Now you can use a simple slice operation to select the first *n* addresses from a network (in this example, I'm selecting the first 10 addresses on each network):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    reserved_ips:
      - network: example1
        reserved: "{{ ('192.168.1.0/24'|to_network)[1:10]|map('string')|list }}"
      - network: example2
        reserved: "{{ ('192.168.2.0/24'|to_network)[1:10]|map('string')|list }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "reserve address {{ item.1 }} for network {{ item.0.network }}"
      loop: "{{ reserved_ips|subelements('reserved') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.network }}/{{ item.1 }}"
```

Which would give me something like:

```
PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.1) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.1 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.2) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.2 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.3) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.3 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.4) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.4 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.5) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.5 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.6) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.6 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.7) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.7 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.8) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.8 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example1/192.168.1.9) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.1.9 for network example1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.1) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.1 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.2) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.2 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.3) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.3 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.4) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.4 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.5) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.5 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.6) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.6 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.7) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.7 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.8) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.8 for network example2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example2/192.168.2.9) => {
    "msg": "reserve address 192.168.2.9 for network example2"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Nice solution. I've adapted the filter a bit, so that the map('string') is not needed:
`def expand_iprange(value): return [str(ip) for ip in netaddr.IPNetwork(value)]`